# Force layout to draw a view/layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Have a look at the picture: the root layout is a `LinearLayout`, horizontal. It contains a `TextView`, the text can be pretty long (I use `singleline` and`ellipsize`), then the image in the second column of the layout won't be visible. Is there a way to force the image/ its layout column to be drawn other than using fixed width values? For example let the layout be drawn from right to left?

[image]

Comment: yes,  use RelativeLayout instead and put ImageView first then tell TextView that should be to the right of ImageView ...

Comment: But when the text in the TextView is too long, it will overlap, won't it?